# Can't get variable out of a function

Tags: python, function

This is a function I created for simple tic-tac-toe assignment. It doesn't seem to return the proper number for the variable `Turn`, although it shows the right value in the output from IPython.  Can anyone help me?

```
#INITIALIZE VARIABLES
CELLS = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

Taken_position = []
X_positions = []
O_positions = []    
Computer_player = ""
Turn = 0 # turn 1 is X

def play_game(Computer_pla   yer, Taken_position, X_positions, O_positions, 
    CELLS, Turn):
    #print("enter")
    if Computer_player == 'X':
    #Turn % 2 != 0: # This is player x
        Turn += 1
        play_position = input("Player X : What square do you want to play?")
        test_num = (int(play_position))
        while test_num in Taken_position:
            play_position = input("Player X : That square is taken!! Try again?")
        add_num = (int(play_position)-1)
        Taken_position.append(play_position) # keep track of all position played
        X_positions.append(play_position) # Keep track of X player, test winner
        CELLS[add_num] = 'X'
    else: # this is O player
        Turn += 1
        play_position = input("Player O : What square do you want to play?")
        test_num2 = (int(play_position))
        while test_num2 in Taken_position:
            play_position = input("Player O : That square is taken!! Try again?")
        add_num = (int(play_position)-1)
        Taken_position.append(play_position) # keep track of all position played
        O_positions.append(play_position) # Keep track of o player, test winner
        CELLS[add_num] = 'O'
    return Taken_position, X_positions, O_positions, CELLS, Turn 

#RUN FUNCTION
play_game(Computer_player, Taken_position, X_positions, O_positions, CELLS, Turn)
```

This is the output I get from IPython. It shows the right output, but the `Turn` variable does not seem to increase when I leave the function.

```
    Player O : What square do you want to play? 2
    Out[318]: (['2'], [], ['2'], [1, 'O', 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 1)
```

Comment: This is quite a lot of code you want us to debug can you be more specific with your issue please.

Comment: Please fix the indentation and take the question out of the code.

Comment: Why should `Turn` increment outside of the function? I think you only call the function once and everything is contained inside that? You could try something like `Turn = play_game(Computer_player, Taken_position, X_positions, O_positions, CELLS, 
Turn)[4]` under `#RUN FUNCTION` but I'm not clear on how your code should work.

Comment: All references to `Turn` within the function correspond to the value you passed as an argument, not the global `Turn` at the start of your script.

Comment: The `play_game` function returns its local `Taken_position, X_positions, O_positions, CELLS, Turn` values but the calling code doesn't save those values, so they get thrown away.

Answer (score 1):

Functions can modify mutable objects in the global scope, but integers like `Turn` cannot be modified because they are immutable. Instead, you probably want to make it explicit what your function is modifying by taking the results of your function and assigning it to variables you initialised. When you call:

```
#RUN FUNCTION
play_game(Computer_player, Taken_position, X_positions, O_positions, CELLS, Turn)
```

you don't assign the returned values to anything, so any changes you see are from global variables being updated. If they aren't mutable, you'll see no change.

This code (I think) gets your existing code base working by updating the global variables by whatever your function returns. However, it will enter an endless loop if you pick a number already chosen. That's because `test_num` is never recalculated during your `while test_num in Taken_position:` loop. That's something for you to look into. You also didn't do anything with `Computer_player` so that turns didn't alternate, but I have fixed that.

```
#INITIALIZE VARIABLES
CELLS = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

Taken_position = []
X_positions = []
O_positions = []    
Computer_player = ""
Turn = 0 # turn 1 is X

def play_game(Computer_player, Taken_position, X_positions, O_positions, 
    CELLS, Turn):
    #print("enter")
    if Computer_player == 'X':
    #Turn % 2 != 0: # This is player x
        Turn += 1
        play_position = input("Player X : What square do you want to play?")
        test_num = (int(play_position))
        while test_num in Taken_position:
            play_position = input("Player X : That square is taken!! Try again?")
        add_num = (int(play_position)-1)
        Taken_position.append(play_position) # keep track of all position played
        X_positions.append(play_position) # Keep track of X player, test winner
        CELLS[add_num] = 'X'
        Computer_player = 'O'
    else: # this is O player
        Turn += 1
        play_position = input("Player O : What square do you want to play?")
        test_num2 = (int(play_position))
        while test_num2 in Taken_position:
            play_position = input("Player O : That square is taken!! Try again?")
        add_num = (int(play_position)-1)
        Taken_position.append(play_position) # keep track of all position played
        O_positions.append(play_position) # Keep track of o player, test winner
        CELLS[add_num] = 'O'
        Computer_player = 'X'
    return Computer_player, Taken_position, X_positions, O_positions, CELLS, Turn 

#RUN FUNCTION
for x in range(5):
    (Computer_player, Taken_position, X_positions, 
    O_positions, CELLS, Turn) = play_game(Computer_player, Taken_position, 
                                        X_positions, O_positions, CELLS, Turn)
```